# Filtering the response of ajax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to filter the ajax response so that I get content of a specific div tag. But it returns empty always. Here is the jquery snippet. Any idea what could be wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:"/testjson.jsp",
    success:function(result){
         var html=result;
         var a=<%=compid%>.id;// gives the div id - jsonoutd36fd7bd8074e310RECID
         alert(a);// This alerts the div id
         var htmlFiltered = $(html).find($(a)).text();
         alert(htmlFiltered);// This alerts empty.

   }});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).find($('#'+a)).text();
```

Comment: And what about: var a=<%=compid%>;  {without getting id property}

Answer (score 1):

```
var a='#'+<%=compid%>.id;
```

...if you want to keep things clean for your find, then dress up the a var.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `#` here to select id

```
$(html).find("#"+a).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is based on what the response from the server looks like. Plus you need to fix the id. Without the #, you would be looking for an element.

---

### With Parent

If the response is nested inside of a parent tag, than what you are doing will work with adding a `#` to your id.

**Response Mark Up:**

```
<div>
   <div id="someId1"></div>
   <div id="yourId"></div>
   <div id="someId2"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var a = "yourId";
var htmlFiltered = $(html).find("#" + a).text();
```

---

### Without Parent

If the response does not have a parent node wrapping the content, you would need to add the parent node or use filter. You also would have to fix the id.

**Response Mark Up:**

```
<div id="someId1"></div>
<div id="yourId"></div>
<div id="someId2"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var a = "yourId";
var htmlFiltered = $(html).filter("#" + a).text();
```

or

```
var a = "yourId";
var htmlFiltered = $("<div/>").html(html).find("#" + a).text();
```